# Android youtube video upload?

Tags: android

In android there are final api for uploading video to youtube and any source code like as a facebook integration in android application??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Facebook and Youtube have their API and SDK for using their content in your application.

Read about the Facebook SDK for Android [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) and about the Youtube API [here](http://code.google.com/intl/iw-IL/apis/youtube/getting_started.html).

I'm not sure about the Youtube API, but I do know that the Facebook SDK for android is open source (I guess that the Youtube API is too, since it is hosted in code.google.com) and they have some examples in their source code project, I suggest you to explore it a little, get familiar with it and read the samples.